# An example of a $G$-torsor as a finite Galois extension

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-number-theory

I was looking for a definition of a $G$-torsor $X \rightarrow Y$ of schemes where $G$ is a finite group acting on $X$ and also considered to act on $Y$ trivially. I have a vague impression that in this case $G$ should act on $X$ [freely and transitively](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/torsor), thus the decomposition group $G_P = \{ \sigma \in G : \sigma(P) = P \}$ for each point $P \in X$ is trivial. Then I looked into examples on Wikipedia, where it states that for a finite Galois extension $L/K$, Spec $L$ $\rightarrow$ Spec $K$ is an example of a G-torsor where $G = Gal(L/K)$. And surely for each prime $\mathfrak{P} \in \text{Spec } L$, its decomposition group can be non-trivial, especially when the extension is ramified at $\mathfrak{P}$. Was I wrong to assume that all decomposition groups should be trivial when we have a $G$-torsor?

Thank you.

Comment: This is one of the cases in algebraic geometry where it is important to distinguish between topological points and scheme-theoretic points. The correct condition (at least in the affine setting) on the action is that for any scheme $Z$ and any point $y \in Y(Z)$, $G(Z)$ acts freely and transitively on the fiber of the associated map $X(Z) \to Y(Z)$ over $y$, provided that the fiber is nonempty.

Comment: As for your actual situation: a torsor should be a faithfully flat $G$-equivariant morphism $X \to Y$ satisfying the condition I mentioned above. You can check that the condition I mention above is tantamount to requiring that the universal map $G \times X \to X \times_{Y} X$ induced by the action $a \colon G \times X \to X$ and projection $p \colon G \times X \to X$ is an isomorphism. In the Galois setting, one needs that the map $L \otimes_{K} L \to \prod_{g \in G} L$ sending $(x, y)$ to $(g(x)y)_{g \in G}$ is an isomorphism. This is a classical Galois theory fact, albeit a nontrivial one.

Comment: @AlexWertheim Thank you very much for pointing out exactly where I'm confused with - I was certainly thinking in terms of topological points. Would you mind clarifying what you mean by the notions $Y(Z)$, $G(Z)$, though? A reference would be perfect for further studying. (This doesn't seem to be introduced in Hartshorne's Algebraic Geometry, the only textbook that sits on my desk all the time.)

Comment: My favorite algebraic geometry text is Ravi Vakil's "Foundations of Algebraic Geometry". You can read about scheme theoretic points starting at Definition 6.3.7. I imagine section 6.6 would also be very helpful for you. As great as Vakil's book is, however, I wouldn't say it takes the ''functor of points'' approach, so if you want to go deeper into this philosophy, you'll likely have to look to other sources. (Large swaths of EGA and SGA are told from this point of view. I can give other suggestions as well, but I should emphasize that I'm not an expert.)